# How to create a dictionary with two querysets from different models, using a common DateTimeField as the dictionary keys?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to create a dictionary from two models with a field `dt` in common. This field should be the dictionary keys, and fields `value` and `last` the keys's value. What is the most efficient way to do that ?

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)
    dt = models.DateTimeField()

class Price(models.Model):
    last = models.FloatField(default=0)
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

The desired output would be something like this :

```
{
    "2022-10-11T00:00:00Z": {
        "value": 151.05,
        "last": 1,
    },
    "2022-10-10T00:00:00Z": {
        "value": 151.1,
        "last": 1.1,
    },
    "2022-10-09T00:00:00Z": {
        "value": 152,
        "last": 1.1,
    },
    "2022-10-08T00:00:00Z": {
        "value": 154,
        "last": 1.23,
    }
}
```

I could iterate through each dictionaries of the querysets with a nested loop and search the items with a common `dt` then populate key:value inside a new dictionary, but it's not elegant and I don't believe it's efficient.

Comment: the data seems badly modelled ... the desired output implies there is a one-to-one relation between Balance and Price, joined by unique dates (and time component not needed?)

Comment: I understand your point, unfortunnatly there isn't such relation between the two models. The two models are independent of each other.

Comment: does every Balance have a corresponding Price?  or there are some days with one but not the other?

Comment: In fact it's the price of an asset and the balance of an account. Both are not directly related but I need to make a comparison between the two. To answer your question, yes, every Balance must have a corresponding Price (same value of the DateTimeField). But the inverse is not true.

Comment: how do you filter out the extra Prices which don't match a Balance then?  ...is it something like only the latest Price in each (one day?) time bucket that needs to be counted?

Comment: You can create 2 pandas dataframe (one for each model) and then use the function `pandas.DataFrame.merge` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to perform the merging by specifying how to perform the merge (inner merge ?) and on which key to perform (`dt`). The pandas API will allow you to specify what behaviors to obtain if some keys are found just once, with the type of merging. Pandas is also able to parse properly dates / times. If your output must be of type dict, look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: @Anentropic I think I will need to filter manually Prices which have a corresponding Balance (same DateTimeField).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do but not so sure about efficiency.

```
import datetime
balances = Balance.objects.annotate(date_only=Cast('dt',DateField())).values("date_only", "value")
prices = Price.objects.annotate(date_only=Cast('dt',DateField())).values("date_only", "last")


data = {}
for (balance, price) in zip(balances, prices):
    str_date = balance['date_only'].strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    if balance['date_only'] == price['date_only']:
        data[str_date] = {}
        data[str_date]['last'] = price['last']
        data[str_date]['value'] = balance['value']


print(data)
```

Comment: would be improved with better variable names: `balance` and `price` should be plural (for the values querysets), and `a` and `b` would be clearer as `balance` and `price`

Comment: efficiency is fine since you only iterate over everything once

Comment: @Anentropic ikr, i had to create new project to solve this :D

Answer (score 1):

This version should cope with the extra unbalanced Price rows described by OP in comments:

```py
balances = (
    Balance
    .objects
    .annotate(date_only=Cast('dt', DateField()))
    .order_by("dt")
    .values("date_only", "value")
)
balance_dates = {balance.dt for balance in balances}
prices = (
    Price
    .objects
    .annotate(date_only=Cast('dt', DateField()))
    .filter(dt__in=balance_dates)
    .order_by("dt")
    .values("date_only", "last")
)

data = {
    balance['date_only'].strftime("%Y/%m/%d"): {
        "last": price["last"],
        "value": balance["value"],
    }
    for (balance, price) in zip(balances, prices)
}
```

Efficiency on the Python side is about the same as Hemal Patel's answer (which this is based on)

But the db query will benefit from an index on `dt` column and could be slow if the tables are very large.

In that case you are probably better off [using raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to output the dataset that you want.